# Show that $2(2^n-2)^{n-1}>(2^n-1)^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 2$.

Tags: inequality

Subject says it all.  Show that $2(2^n-2)^{n-1}>(2^n-1)^{n-1}$ for all $n\geq 2$.  I am confident that it is true but a proof has remained elusive.

Comment: Looks to me like the LHS is even, but the RHS is odd.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I agree.  Does this help to show that the LHS is larger than the RHS?

Comment: @Lucas no, but I think Tim misread the "$>$" for "$=$".

Comment: Sorry I misread the question.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First show by induction that $n \leq 2^{n-1}$ for all $n \geq 1$. Then by Bernoulli's inequality for $n \geq 2$

$$
\left(\frac{2^n-2}{2^n-1}\right)^{n-1} = \left(1-\frac{1}{2^n-1}\right)^{n-1} \geq 1 - \frac{n-1}{2^n-1} > 1-\frac{n}{2^n} \geq \frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: That is so slick.

Answer (score 2):

The inequality is equivalent to

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{2(2^n-1)} \right)^n < 2$$

Look at the LHS:

$$\left( 1+\frac{1}{2(2^n-1)} \right)^n = \left(\left( 1+\frac{1}{2(2^n-1)} \right)^{2(2^n-1)}\right)^{\frac{n}{2(2^n-1)}} \leq e^{\frac{n}{2(2^n-1)}} = \sqrt{e}^{\frac{n}{2^n-1}}$$.

The assertion follows now from $\frac{n}{2^n-1} \leq 1$ and $\sqrt{e} < 2$.

Answer (score 0):

That is equivalent to:
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2^n-2}\right)^{n-1}<2.\tag{1}$$
Since the sequence given by $a_m=\left(1+\frac{1}{m}\right)^m$ is increasing and converging towards $e$, it is enough to show that:
$$ L_n=(n-1)\leq (2^n-2)\log 2=R_n \tag{2}$$
for any $n\geq 1$. That is easily achieved by induction, since $(2)$ holds for $n=1$ and:
$$ L_{n+1}-L_n = 1,\qquad R_{n+1}-R_n = 2^n\log 2, \tag{3}$$
so we just need to prove $2\log 2>1$, or $e<4$ that is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extensive operation on this inequality to prove its correctness. You can perform an easy comparison of the coefficients and the term inside parentheses. The left side has a coefficient of 2 and the right side has a coefficient of 1 and it's clear that 2 > 1. Inside the parentheses on the left side there is a -2 and on the right side there is a -1. Everything else is the same on both side. The coefficient of 2 on the left side compensate this -1 difference and hence the inequality is true for n > 2.